# Passar valor por header para API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bom dia pessoal estou com o seguindo problema, tenho uma API para ser consumida, porém ela espera um token de retorno validado internamente, esse token é passado como parâmetro via cabeçalho, porém não uso o JWT, pego um token gerado pelo banco. Minha duvida está justamente em como enviar via header essa valor, para fazer com que a API receba. Nunca fiz esse processo, o código que tenho hoje é esse.

```
application.get('/listarEmpresas', function(req, res) {

    var request = require('request');

    request('APIURL', function(error, response, body) {

        console.log('error:', error);
        let url = req.url
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log('body:', body);
        var arrayJSON = JSON.parse(body);

    });
});
```

Ficarei grato quem puder me dar uma luz.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode passar os parâmetros para a função `get`:

```
const headers = {
  token: 'TEXTO DO TOKEN',
};

const parametros = {
  url: 'APIURL',
  headers,
};

request.get(parametros)...
```

Comment: Bom dia Sorack, obrigado por esse ensinamento, funcionou perfeitamente!.

Comment: @Roberto A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).